# MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED after update

Tags: mongodb

After updating linux i can't start my mongodb.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-249 mongodb]$ sudo systemctl start mongod
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-249 mongodb]$ sudo systemctl status mongod
● mongod.service - MongoDB Database Server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Mon 2023-02-27 08:12:14 UTC; 4s ago
     Docs: https://docs.mongodb.org/manual
  Process: 3296 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3296 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Stopped MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: start request repeated too quickly for mongod.service
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Failed to start MongoDB Database Server.
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: Unit mongod.service entered failed state.
Feb 27 08:12:14 ip-172-31-28-249.eu-south-1.compute.internal systemd[1]: mongod.service failed.
```

and whet i try connect mongosh i get this

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-28-249 mongodb]$ mongosh
Current Mongosh Log ID: 63fc6638bdf3ce7a41cefff7
Connecting to:          mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/?directConnection=true&serverSelectionTimeoutMS=2000&appName=mongosh+1.7.1
MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:27017
```

in mongod.log i get this

```
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.413+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23285,   "ctx":"-","msg":"Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.416+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4915701, "ctx":"main","msg":"Initialized wire specification","attr":{"spec":{"incomingExternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"incomingInternalClient":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"outgoing":{"minWireVersion":0,"maxWireVersion":13},"isInternalClient":true}}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.417+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.417+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":4648601, "ctx":"main","msg":"Implicit TCP FastOpen unavailable. If TCP FastOpen is required, set tcpFastOpenServer, tcpFastOpenClient, and tcpFastOpenQueueSize."}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.425+00:00"},"s":"W",  "c":"ASIO",     "id":22601,   "ctx":"main","msg":"No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup"}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.425+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationDonorService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationDonors"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.425+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"REPL",     "id":5123008, "ctx":"main","msg":"Successfully registered PrimaryOnlyService","attr":{"service":"TenantMigrationRecipientService","ns":"config.tenantMigrationRecipients"}}
{"t":{"$date":"2023-02-27T08:12:13.426+00:00"},"s":"I",  "c":"CONTROL",  "id":23330,   "ctx":"main","msg":"ERROR: Cannot write pid file to {path_string}: {errAndStr_second}","attr":{"path_string":"/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid","errAndStr_second":"No such file or directory"}}
```

The PORT 27017 is open
[image: as ports]

what can i do to fix this error?

Comment: Please don't paste screenshots, use formatted text. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Comment: Check the logfile `/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log`

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit i corrected the question, thank you.
I also posted the mongod.log content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your service file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`

Usually it should contain lines like these:

```
[Service]
User=mongod
Group=mongod
Environment="OPTIONS=-f /etc/mongod.conf"
EnvironmentFile=-/etc/sysconfig/mongod
ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod $OPTIONS
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mkdir -p /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chown mongod:mongod /var/run/mongodb
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/chmod 0755 /var/run/mongodb
PermissionsStartOnly=true
PIDFile=/var/run/mongodb/mongod.pid
```

I assume folder `/var/run/mongodb` was deleted (see
[Directory in /var/run gets deleted after hard reboot](https://serverfault.com/questions/74796/directory-in-var-run-gets-deleted-after-hard-reboot)), thus you must create it and grant permissions when service is started.

Note, you should not edit file `/usr/lib/systemd/system/mongod.service` directly. Instead create a copy at `/etc/systemd/system/mongod.service` and modify this copy according to your needs.